# Clearing Android RadioGroup

Tags: android, reset, radio-group

I have a RadioGroup with 3 buttons inside a Fragment.  I have a requirement to clear off this radiogroup buttons when the user makes such a choice.  On googling, I found out the the Radiogroup's clearCheck() method should work, but it doesn't.  So I tried to loop through the radiogroup's radiobuttons and use the radiobutton's setChecked(false) method to uncheck them one at a time, but that doesn't seem to work either.  I am obviously doing something silly here.  Could you help spot it for me please?  Thanks.  Here's the code:

```
rdoGrp = (RadioGroup) getView().findViewById(R.id.rdoGrpTest1);
for (int i = 0; i < rdoGrp.getChildCount(); i++) {
   System.out.println("Clearing buttons");
   rb1 = (RadioButton) rdoGrp.getChildAt(i);
   rb1.setChecked(false);
}
//   rdoGrp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
//   rdoGrp.clearCheck();
//   rdoGrp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
```

Comment: I'm guessing there is something wrong with the `rdoGrp`. Try to log the child count on it.

Comment: @Shaishav  I displayed the value of i and I get a count of 3 (0, 1, 2), and there are 3 radiobuttons within the the radiogroup.

Comment: Try passing the view in your clearCheck() method instead using getView() method.

Comment: Intriguing. Can you post your full fragment code and xml?

Comment: @Shaishav I am so sorry to waste your time guys!  Shaishav's request for the full code made me look at the entire thing, and I saw that I had my clearCheck in the onStart method, but in onResume, I had another piece of code resetting the original value!!! :-(  Once I corrected the error, the clearCheck() method works!  Sorry about that again, and thanks for your feedback

Comment: No worries. It happens :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain how the user make the request? is it on button click?

does it make the choice from the activity or the fragment?

BTW i tried to use

mRadioGroup.clearCheck();

and its works fine to me, try to change

```
rdoGrp = (RadioGroup) getView().findViewById(R.id.rdoGrpTest1);
```

to

```
rdoGrp = (RadioGroup) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.rdoGrpTest1);
```

Comment: I tried getActivity() as well, but it was a logical error, thanks for your input and sorry it was a stupid logical error on my part :-(

Comment: no worries happen to all of us!  can you share the error so i will avoid doing the same in the future? =)

Comment: sure.  I have 2 Fragments - Fragment A and Fragment B.  There's a (radiobutton) question in Fragment A which decides if another group of radiobuttons in Fragment needs to be open for data entry or not.  If the user enters 'Yes' in Fragment A, then enters makes their choices in Fragment B; and then decides to go back to Fragment A, and changes their answer to 'No', then I need to clear out the radiogroup selections in Fragment B (made earlier). I was clearing out the choices in the onStart method in Fragment B, but in Fragment B's onResume method, I was restoring the original values from before

Comment: So I added an IF statement to make sure to re-populate the values, only when the user response is still 'Yes'

Comment: OHH make 100% sense to fall there, thanks for your respond =)